# How to make imenu recognize union of c language

Tags: imenu

Although the format of `struct` in C language is the same as that of `union`, `imenu` can only recognize `struct`, not `union`.

I want `imenu` to recognize `union` like `struct`, and simply list the both side by side (no need to distinguish them), how can I do that?

Comment: See `cc-imenu-c-generic-expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Class` entry there was `class\\|struct`, change that to `class\\|struct\\|union`

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
      (defun my-c-mode-hook ()
          (setcar (cdr (assoc "Class" imenu-generic-expression ))
              "^\\(template[    ]*<[^>]+>[  ]*\\)?\\(class\\|struct\\|union\\)[     ]+\\([[:alnum:]_]+\\(<[^>]+>\\)?\\)\\([     \n]\\|\\\\\n\\)*[:{]")))
```